# Scrollable sidebar with full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, sidebar

I am currently writing on an Angular application that has a top fixed bootstrap navbar and a sidebar container that consists of a sidebar header and a scrollable sidebar list that displays some content.

Therefor I use the following CSS classes:

```
.main-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar-container {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sidebar-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And the following html code:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">      
    <div class="sidebar-container col-xs-3">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-view col-xs-9 pull-right">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The following jsfiddle is a minimal working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/j1tuw3vj/8/

My problem is, that the sidebar is moved beyond the bottom of the page so the last element of the list is invisible. I cannot move it up by setting a negative margin and a padding to the sidebar, because I don't know the actual height of the sidebar header (its height can change in different views).

Answer (score 1):

**Replace:**

```
/* Scrollable sidebar. */
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**With:**

```
/* Scrollable sidebar. */
.sidebar {
    height: 85%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**The problem is:**
You adjusted the sidebar `height` to 100% and the position is `relative`.

**See it** [Live](https://jsfiddle.net/j1tuw3vj/9/).

**UPDATE:**

add this line to your css file.

```
.nav-pills li:last-child{
margin-bottom:80px;
}
```

**See Update** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/j1tuw3vj/10/).

Comment: The problem is, that I want the sidebar to use the rest of the available height. With a value less the 100% there is either empty space below the sidebar or if the header grows to much, it is pushed below the bottom of the window.